# Angular Directive - React to a hosts output

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a directive that i use on input fields.

```
<input myDirective [ngModel]="model" (ngModelChange)="doSomething()">
```

Now in the "myDirective" i want to react to the inputs "ngModelChange"-Output.

Background: The directive does something to the input if the input is not empty. 
Now, i tried using `@HostListener`to get the event and check if the model contains anything. But: If i set the model in a parent component, that solution can't work because there is no event fired on the input.

**Full minimal example:**

Template:

```
  <input myDirective [ngModel]="model" (ngModelChange)="model = $event; someFunction()">
```

Directive:

```
@Input() model: any
fun reactToChanges(){
    if(this.model.length > 0){doSomething}
}
```

my current solution:

```
@HostListener('input', ['$event']) onEvent($event) {
   this.reactToChanges()
}
```

Parent component:

```
fun foo(newValue){
   //this does not trigger the directives function, but it has to
   this.model = newValue
}
```

If `foo`is triggered, of course the @HostListener doesn't go off.

Comment: What if you implement `ngOnChanges` ?

Comment: You mean implementing `ngOnChanges` in the directive? That doesnt get triggered when the model of the Host changes